# Why is the phrase "assure you" used so much in Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-voyager

The phrases "I can assure you..." and "I assure you" are used very often in *Star Trek* shows. The phrase is used so much that it seems as if its frequency must be a deliberate choice by the writers.

### Exhibit A

Searching the transcripts with Google searches like this (thanks to user [hypnosifl](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/22250/hypnosifl)):

`"I can assure you" site:chakoteya.net/StarTrek`

we find the following data:

```
|--------+----------------+--------------------+----------|
| Series | "I assure you" | "I can assure you" | Fraction |
|--------+----------------+--------------------+----------|
|  TOS   |      59        |         3          |    78%   |
|  TNG   |       0        |         0          |     0%   |
|  DS9   |      39        |        18          |    32%   |
|  VOY   |      61        |        19          |    46%   |
|  ENT   |      16        |         2          |    18%   |
|--------+----------------+--------------------+----------|
```

The "Fraction" column is the number of search hits divided by the total number of episodes (I didn't check whether the search returns multiple hits if the phrase is uttered more than once per episode).

I am certain that the numbers are underestimates for TNG because I know that Picard says "assure you" at least once. <s>In fact the search `"well there it sits" site:chakoteya.net/TNG"` yields zero results, which is obviously wrong because that phrase is uttered in "The Measure of a Man".</s> We need the comma, i.e. "Well, there it sits".

### Exhibit B

Back in 2009, Vulture published [this article](https://www.vulture.com/2009/04/star_trek.html) with the headline *"J.J. Abrams Wants to Assure You That His Star Trek Is Not Just for Nerds"*. Coincidence? I say no, there's a conspiracy here!

### Question

So, with so many occurrences of the phrase in one hand, and evidence that the search has underestimated the true occurrence in the other, I ask you: has any writer, cast member, or anyone else attached to the production ever commented on an in or **out of universe** reason for the unusually high recurrence of the phrase "...assure you..." in Star Trek series?

Comment: While I can't address the frequency of the phrase "I can assure you" in the 90s Star Trek shows, I can address the frequency of the phrase in ordinary language. Using [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+can+assure+you&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20can%20assure%20you%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CI%20can%20assure%20you%3B%2Cc0) to measure the frequency of "I can assure you" in English texts, (cont.)

Comment: ... it turns out to be relatively common in the 19th century, then flags a bit before reviving from about 1940 to 1980. After that it reaches an all-time low in the late 1990s, about when the Star Trek shows you ask about were being made. And now "I can assure you" is on the rise again. Which may have sensitized you to the phrase in these 90s shows.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be used *that* much, [searching the transcripts site chakoteya.net](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+can+assure+you%22+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FStarTrek+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FTNG+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FDS9+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FVoyager+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FEnterprise&ei=0trHYMCnIZiVwbkPpqakmAs&oq=%22I+can+assure+you%22+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FStarTrek+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FTNG+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FDS9+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FVoyager+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FEnterprise) I only get 29 episodes that use it in all of TOS, TNG, DS9, VOY and ENT.

Comment: "I assure you" is used more often though (about 160 results), see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22assure+you%22+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FStarTrek+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FTNG+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FDS9+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FVoyager+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FEnterprise&ei=gtzHYMKUBuWbwbkPs8iawAM&oq=%22assure+you%22+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FStarTrek+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FTNG+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FDS9+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FVoyager+OR+site%3Achakoteya.net%2FEnterprise).

Comment: "The phrase is used so much that it seems as if its frequency must be a deliberate choice by the writers" — Is it used more in *Star Trek* than in other American TV shows in the same period? Where's a hardcore *LA Law* nerd when you need one...

Comment: That a phrase is used often is no indication that the use is deliberate. Writers are quite capable of falling into patterns and using standard phrases for certain situations.

Comment: @Harabeck First of all, it's used so much across several shows that it seems self-evident that the writers did it on purpose. Second, see in the edited question that references to the phase have spilled over into articles written *about* Star Trek. So I think there's an in-joke going on here in some capacity. It *could* be spontaneous, it *could* be deliberate, and what I've asked in the question is the decidedly not-opinion-based question of whether or not anyone associated with the production has ever commented on the phenomenon.

Comment: @DanielSank Yeah, I don't buy your conspiracy with the article, that's called confirmation bias. As for using it across shows, they shared, writers, or the writers worked together, or the writers were inspired by watching the previous work. I *might* be on purpose, but it doesn't have to be, and it's an awfully subtle in-joke if it is on purpose.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126527/discussion-on-question-by-danielsank-why-is-the-phrase-assure-you-used-so-much).

Comment: I think if you broke it down by character you might find it concentrated around certain characters. After all, it's not unusual for people (and by extension TV characters) to have certain stock phrases they like to use.

Comment: TNG : The Wounded. The Enemy. The Measure Of A Man. Lessons. (and those are just the ones I found with 'Picard says "assure you" ')

Comment: Are you sure these Google counts are accurate? If you search for "rest assured" on that site, via Google, Worf's line "rest assured, Commander" does not show up, even though it's there plain as day on http://chakoteya.net/NextGen/116.htm